Installing Flutter on Ubuntu 22.04 fails with unmet dependency error and -f doesn't work either
I am trying to install Flutter on my Ubuntu 22 and the dependencies installed, system upto date. No issues. System info:
64 bit system.
Ubuntu 22.04 installed.
For some reason Flutter doc suggest installing these 32 bit packages.
But when I try this step-
sudo apt-get install \
libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 \
libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 \
libbz2-1.0:i386

It fails with the output-
      Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
  requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
  distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
  or been moved out of Incoming.
  The following information may help to resolve the situation:

  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  apt : Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: gpgv or
              gpgv2 but it is not going to be installed or
              gpgv1 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.11) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libseccomp2 (>= 2.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
  base-files : PreDepends: awk
              Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
  base-passwd : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
              Depends: libdebconfclient0 (>= 0.145) but it is not going to be installed
  bash : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
  bsdutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: bsdextrautils
  coreutils : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.44) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libgmp10 (>= 2:6.2.1+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
  dash : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
  debianutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
  diffutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
  dpkg : PreDepends: libbz2-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: liblzma5 (>= 5.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libzstd1 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
  e2fsprogs : PreDepends: libblkid1 (>= 2.36) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libcom-err2 (>= 1.43.9) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libext2fs2 (= 1.46.5-2ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libss2 (>= 1.38) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: logsave
              Recommends: e2fsprogs-l10n but it is not going to be installed
  findutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
  grep : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: libpcre3 but it is not going to be installed
  gzip : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
  hostname : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
  init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
  libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.35) but it is not installable
              Depends: libc6 (< 2.36) but it is not installable
  libcrypt1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.25) but it is not installable
  login : PreDepends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libpam-runtime but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libpam-modules but it is not going to be installed
  ncurses-bin : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6.3) but it is not going to be installed
  perl-base : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.35) but it is not installable
  sed : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
  shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                          grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not installable
              Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24)
              Depends: mokutil (>= 0.3.0+1538710437.fb6250f-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: sbsigntool but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: secureboot-db but it is not going to be installed
  sysvinit-utils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
  tar : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
  util-linux : PreDepends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libblkid1 (>= 2.37.2) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libcap-ng0 (>= 0.7.9) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libmount1 (>= 2.37.2) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libsmartcols1 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
  E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Not sure how to deal with the issue. i386 already configured.

I suggest ask the flutter people what the issue is. They do list Ubuntu 22.04 as a supported version. Their web site says 64 bit versions only so not sure why you are using 32 bit stuff. https://docs.flutter.dev/reference/supported-platforms

@David my system is 64 bit too. But in their doc they require me to install these 32 bit packages for some reason related to android studio.

It would be a good idea to edit the question and add this critical detail.

The exact problem is with kind of packages that flutter used have breaking dependency with 64 bits ubuntu. Ubuntu users can easy escape this  with snaps.
I had same issue. I solved my problem with flutter snap.
https://snapcraft.io/flutter

This might be the solution test it. Thanks!
